# Batch file running Python script

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

What I would like to do is create a batch file that will temporarily add a environment variable to the Python executable. From there call the executable and open another script from the batch file. I'm very new to batch and have been researching this, so far I've found that to add a environment variable I would need something like:

```
set env="path/to/exe"
```

And to call a script I would need to use:

```
call "path/to/script"
```

My question being, if I where to combine the two two and then call the script, would I be able to do something like this:

```
set env="python.exe"
call "python script.py"
```

Will this work like I would expect it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the `CALL` is used for calling (opening) batch files. If you wanted to open a python script through batch (and set the environment) you would have use the `START`command and code it like this:

```
set env=python.exe
start python script.py
```

This should work (combined) if you have the Python environment.

Comment: The executable will be in the directory that the script is located in, I don't know if this will work yet it's still a work in progress, well more of an idea in progress. Do you think the call command will still work as expected with what you now know?

Comment: The **CALL** as far to my knowledge is to start Batch applications only, however the start command starts all file types.

Comment: You must remove the _space_ after the `=` sign, otherwise it becomes part of the variable value...

Comment: @PryroTech, you need to _remove_ the space, not to add another one -- see [my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41194781/3); in addition, I recommend to use the quoted syntax `set "env=python.exe"`...